# Can't start mysql on Fedora 19

Tags: fedora, mysql

I'm running Fedora 19 and I have installed MySQL using `yum install mysql`.

When I issue the `mysql` command, I get the following error message:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

If I do create the /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock file the number after the error message change to `(111)` (it is possible that I have created the file with wrong permissions).

After reading to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63391/mysql-stop-waiting-issues-cant-connect-through-socket) and [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49183/mysql-not-getting-started-on-linux) I tried to `service mysqld start`, but I get:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status mysqld.service' for details.
```

and `service mysqld status` returns

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  mysqld.service
mysqld.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package `mysql` is the client package. You need to install the server package:

```
$ sudo yum install mysql-server
```

Additionally, starting in Fedora 19, [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) is now the default implementation of MySQL. MariaDB is a fork of MySQL.

> MariaDB, a community developed fork of MySQL, will be the default implementation of MySQL in Fedora 19.

*source: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ReplaceMySQLwithMariaDB*